# Pygame import error

Tags: python, pygame

When I installed pygame and tried to run import pygame, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried Googling the issue? One of the top results is [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9088051/866022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on a Mac?  The last bit of that error message: "no matching architecture in universal wrapper" is a clue that there is a 32-bit vs. 64-bit conflict.

I'll refer you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275808/installing-pygame-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8) from not that long ago.  That person had the exact same problem as you.  One of the answerers was able to fix it.